# What JavaScript is needed to add options to TOP of <select> dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have successfully added the following code that adds options to the BOTTOM of a  options list but I want to add these values to the TOP of the dropdown list. I've been playing with the following code but how to add to the TOP of the dropdowns???

```js
var example_array = {
  ValueA: 'Text A',
  ValueB: 'Text B',
  ValueC: 'Text C'
};

var select = document.getElementById("country_4962");
for (index in example_array) {
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(example_array[index], index);
}
```

```html
<select id="country_4962"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `insertBefore` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```js
var example_array = {
  ValueA: 'Text A',
  ValueB: 'Text B',
  ValueC: 'Text C'
};

var select = document.getElementById("country_4962");
for (index in example_array) {
document.getElementById("country_4962").insertBefore(new Option(example_array[index], index), document.getElementById("country_4962").firstChild);
  
}
```

```html
<select id="country_4962"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to organize your select options...

If you want to put a single value at the top of the list, put this before your for loop starts:

```
<option selected value id="default">-- Select --</option>
```

If you want to organize your data alphabetically (this sorts results from a foreach loop, but sorting feature is the same). You can change the sort feature to sort how you'd like, depending on how you want your select options to appear. It also uses the default value if you'd want to put a value at the top of the Select:

```
<select id="Name" name="Name" onclick="customizeTable()" >
                            <option selected value id="default">-- Select --</option>
                        @foreach (var item in example_array)
                        {
                            <option value="@item">@item</option>
                        }
                    </select>

<script>
var selectOption = $('select#Name option');
    var arr = selectOption.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
    selectOption.each(function(i, o) {
      o.value = arr[i].v;
      $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });
</script>
```